# How do I add transitions between switch result cases?

Tags: swiftui, switch-statement, uiswitch

Currently, my code uses a series of switch result cases that asks questions and presents different answer choices. For example, when the user clicks Evening, the code will present a new question with the answer choices being "Sweet" and "Savory". How can I put a cool transition where the "Morning" and "Evening" choices turn into the "Sweet" and "Savory" choices? Open to any transitions that you'd recommend.

```
var body: some View {
    
    let cardWidth = 300
    let cardWidthValue = CGFloat(cardWidth)
    
    let cardHeight = 300
    let cardHeightValue = CGFloat(cardHeight)
    
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.4))
                .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 20)
            
            switch result {
            case "Start":
                VStack{
                    Text("What time is it?")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30.0, weight: .bold))
                    HStack {
                        Button  {
                            result = "M"
                        } label: {
                            Text("Morning")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 165, height: 100)
                                .background(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        Button  {
                            result = "E"
                        } label: {
                            Text("Evening☀️")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 165, height: 100)
                                .background(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
                }
            case "E":
                VStack{
                    Text("Sweet or Savory?")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30.0, weight: .bold))
                    HStack {
                        Button  {
                            result = "EveningSweet"
                        } label: {
                            Text("Sweet")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 165, height: 100)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        
                        Button  {
                            result = "EveningSavory"
                        } label: {
                            Text("Savory")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 165, height: 100)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `withAnimation{}` to animate your event.

Let's say you want to animate views after you click on `Evening`:

```
   Button  {
       withAnimation { //here
           result = "E" 
       }
   } label: {
     Text("Evening☀️")
         .foregroundColor(Color.white)
         .frame(width: 165, height: 100)
         .background(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
         .cornerRadius(10)
    }
```

This mean that all views that are related to this event of `result = "E"` shall be animated. The default transition of all animation is `.opacity`.

After trying the first case, if you want to change transition type, use `.transition()`

```
case "E":
    VStack {

    }.transition(.slide)
```

You will see a different animation from the first time that you did not set transition equals to slide.

I would recommend you try the first option without `.slide` first to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only question, where in the code do I put the withAnimation? Would you mind showing me one example?

Comment: Sure. For general usage, you use withAnimation{} around any `set value event of variable`. For example: withAnimation{ isClicked.toggle() or result = "E"}. I added new sample in the above answer. You can check.

Comment: Sweet, thanks so much! Just one more question, how do I make the transition last longer (duration increase) and/or delay?

Comment: withAnimation(.default.speed(0.5)) {result = "E" }, use speed to control your animation time. less than 1 = slower, 1 = normal speed, more than 1 = faster.

Comment: great. thanks again for everything! really really helps a ton